# How to unset (delete) POST variable in python (Django)

Tags: python, django, session, post, django-views

I am a beginner with Django and Python ! I am stuck with a problem !

I try to make a system of session in my software. When user are disconnected (through a button), Users are redirected to the connection page.

Unfortunatly, ***form.is_valid()*** is still valid, so automatically user is connected again.

i don't know why ? How can I do to reset form or POST value.

Thank You,

Thomas

**ps :** The code for the connection's view (in views.py of my app) is :

```
def connexion(request):
contact_form = Connect(request.POST or None)

if contact_form.is_valid():
    print(contact_form.cleaned_data["id"])
    user_check = uc(contact_form.cleaned_data["id"], contact_form.cleaned_data["pwd"])
    if user_check.identity_verified:
        request.session['usr'] = user_check.get_compact_value()
        return redirect(home)
    else:
        return render(request, 'conn\\connexion.html', {'form': Connect, 'errorId': True})
    del user_check
else:
    return render(request, 'conn\\connexion.html', {'form': Connect, 'errorId': False})
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should change here.

Firstly, you should only do the form validation if the request is a POST.

Secondly, you should always redirect after a post request, even if it's back to the same page; this will reset the values.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `del` is after the return so it never gets executed. But you should be doing this at all.

Your trouble is because you have not followed the standard django pattern of redirecting after successful form submission.

```
def connexion(request):

    contact_form = Connect(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            print(contact_form.cleaned_data["id"])
            user_check = uc(contact_form.cleaned_data["id"], contact_form.cleaned_data["pwd"])
            if user_check.identity_verified:
                request.session['usr'] = user_check.get_compact_value()
                return redirect(home) # redirect ok
            else:
                return redirect('somewhere else')
    return render(request, 'conn\\connexion.html', {'form': Connect, 'errorId': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty,
I find ! I used ajax to call the view (why? i didn't remenber !)
Now i just use `<a href='...'></a>` and it's ok  !